# Google Maps Api camera doesn't rotate properly on coordinate

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps API and I want to set my camera on a specific marker. When I do this and I start rotating my camera is losing focus on my marker while they both have the same coordinate.

Does someone knows why this is happening?

My code

```
LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        player.setPosition(myCoordinates);
        CameraPosition currentPosition = map.getCameraPosition();
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(myCoordinates)
                .bearing(currentPosition.bearing)
                .zoom(18)
                .tilt(currentPosition.tilt)
                .build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Click [here](https://stefmorren.stackstorage.com/s/q4GXyASsChCv9Wn) for a video of the problem. (The orange marker is one that the camera is set on)

Comment: Video that demonstrates the issue is not available.

Comment: Fixed the video.